# Accessing variable value from inside ansible playbook

Tags: rhel, variable, ansible

I have used the following variable in ansible playbook as shown below.

```
---
  - hosts: hosts
    vars:
      vers: 18.7
```

I am trying to access the value of `vers` using `$` under tasks as shown below

```
    tasks:
  - name: COpy war file
    copy:
      src: /etc/puppet/warrepo/japp-$ver.war
      dest: /data/dist/app/
```

But looks like it is not working . Please suggest how to access the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2). Correct syntax is

```
src: "/etc/puppet/warrepo/japp-{{ ver }}.war"
```